# jQuery combine .ready and .resize functions

Tags: jquery

As the title says, I have exactly the same code needs to run in both functions. Is there a way to put them together and run as one function please? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes.  Simply define a function with the common code and pass that as the argument to the two methods.

```
var callback = function () {
  // This is the common code
};

$(document).ready(callback);
$(window).resize(callback);
```

Comment: Why do you use a var instead of just naming the function?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {

}).trigger('resize');
```