# How to only move the horizontal scrollbar to right

Tags: css

When using `body {direction:rtl;}` the horizontal scrollbar starts from the right, but in some browsers the vertical scrollbar also changes position (i.e. moves to the left). How can I avoid moving the vertical scrollbar and only change the direction of the horizontal scrollbar?

**Update:**

I've found that by setting `someMainContainer {float:right;}` I can force the page view to start from the right side. But this way, the horizontal scrollbar disappears! Any ideas?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div/14150577#14150577

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem fully, but would setting `overflow-x: hidden` work for your problem?

You could also use this function in jQuery:

```
$(element).scroll(function () {
    this.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

This will basically force the page to scroll back to the top. You could use `scrollLeft` if you wanted to disable horizontal scrolling or both to disable all scrolling. In your case, the scrolling element would be `window`. A revised function:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    this.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

To scroll page to the right on page load, you could use the following after the document is ready (i.e `$(document.ready()`):

```
var rightPos = $(document).outerWidth() - $(window).width();
$('html, body').scrollLeft(rightPos);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant. My question is about changing the starting point of the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: When you say "starting point" do you mean the scroll position? because you could set that with Javascript as well.

Comment: Yes. When opening the webpage, I want the horizontal scrollbar to be set to right.

Comment: Edited post to include code to scroll all the way to the right. Not sure if you mean stylistically or programmatically "set" still though.

Comment: Basically, I prefer to do it stylistically, but right now any working solution will do. It seems to me that your solution has a flaw, though; when maximizing the window and then minimizing it again, the scroll is again at the left.

Comment: Yeah. I'm kind of doing this on the fly. You can add a 'resize' event listener, which would cover that. It would be `$(window).resize(function(){ var rightPos = $(document).outerWidth() - $(window).width(); $('html, body').scrollLeft(rightPos); });`

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post a jsfiddle of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had just found the `resize` event listener and wanted to add it here, and saw your new comment. As I am quite new to jquery, could you please tell me how should I use both `$(document.ready()` and `$(window).resize` in a correct way? Right now I'm just using `$( document ).ready(function() {
 //the code
 });
 $(window).resize(function() {
 //the code reapeted again
 });`

Comment: I found the rest of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7955727/1778592). Thanks @lewiguez, I mark this as answer. But, if anyone happened to know how to do the job with only css, please share it with us here.